# Installing gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu cross compiler on raspberry pi 3

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi3, arm64

I am trying to compiled aarch64 code from raspberry pi 3 which raspbian does not support, thus trying to install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu

However I get this error during install
gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu: Depends: gcc-5-aarch64-linux-gnu (>= 5.2.1-13cross1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

The way I understand this, the repositories have missing dependencies. Any suggestions on how to fix this?